# Opening new tab with selenium python(3) and performing functions on it

Tags: python, selenium

Take an example of Facebook

I have the main page in the driver object

I have the url of the element I want to access(comments of first post)

1 how can I open it another tab

2 will this new tab be saved in some sort of object just like driver(so that I can perform actions on it)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Just grab the link and initialize a new driver object with it. Not too difficult...

Comment: @MattDMo but i think it will be a new session. I want to do things in the same session on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I have reached the solution.

For getting button of the desired link we can do this:

```
button = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,'login' )))
```

when you have the button that you want to click then do this

```
storyButton.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

for transferring control to the second tab we can do this

```
tabs = driver.window_handles #creates a list of tabs
driver.switch_to_window(tabs[1])  #switches driver control to the second tab
```

now every thing will be done in the second tab until controls are shifted back to the first tab